# How to regulate a led on-board?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button, potentiometer, project

There is **blink project** consisting 3 sections:

***1 - regulation of the led brightness using a potentiometer***

***2 - whenever: the button is pressed - the led is on***

***-   the button is released - the led is off***

***3 - change state of a led statically***

The question is that:

May I make this project on-board?
I am curious that, if I will try making this project on-board (Arduino UNO) will the Arduino damaged?

Comment: When the button is released, the led is off, but at the same time the brightness is regulated with a potentiometer. Those two things can not be done at the same time.

Comment: "making this project on-board"? what do you understand by that?

Comment: @Juraj Using just Arduino UNO board, not using extra breadboard and led. There are 11 leds like: ON, R17, R6, AX,.. and so on. As I unerstood on-board project is done just using these leds. If I am wrong, would be so glad to learn what on-board and off-board means? )))

Comment: so it should be "making this project by using on-board LED"? button or pot should not be on-board

Comment: only on-board LED controllable from the sketch is LED on pin 13. and it is not dimmable as you can read in the Answer by Kevin

Comment: there are only 4 LEDs on Uno R3. RX, TX for Serial lines, power and L on pin 13

Comment: @Juraj So we can connect a potentiometer and button to regulate the led(pin 13), right?

Comment: NO, it is not dimmable. you can turn it on and off with a button. (and the button is not on board)

Comment: If you really want to dimm the onboard LED, you can bitbang the PWM signal by setting the state of pin 13 directly in your code (changing rapidly between high and low, with a variable ratio of high to low time). But this means, that you will not be able to do much else.

Comment: @chrisl,  the LED on D13 can be dimmed using standard blink without delay coding.  Turn it on, monitor the time going by, when enough has passed then turn off the LED. Do that at a "fast enough" rate, say every 5mS, and it appear to be dimmed. For brighter, have more on-time than off-time. For dimmer, have more off-time than on-time.  The code can lots of other stuff while waiting for the time to pass for the next transition. This is basically bit-banged PWM as mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: @chrisl, good idea. I hope marvB will come back and read it. (including the end :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Pin 13, which is the on-board LED, is not a pwm pin. So you cannot Control the brightness of that LED on-board. You will have to use another LED and a PWM pin.